# ActiveXObject(Excel) leaves EXCEL.EXE *32 in Procces <Javascript>

Tags: javascript, excel

```
var Excel = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');

Excel.Visible = false;
var Excel_file = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Worksheet);
}

if(x == 2)
{
Excel_file.close(false);
Excel.Quit();
Excel.Application.Quit();
Excel = null;
Excel_file = null;

window.setTimeout(CollectGarbage, 10);
//Excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
}
```

[Windows Task Manager Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLO3f.png)

I use ActiveXObject to open the excel application behind the scenes, perform my function (defined and called elsewhere) and then close it out. The problem is that through task manager, each time I run the program, it creates a new instance of EXCEL.EXE *32 in the process section.

This script is on a webpage and it will be run very often throughout the day. It is not feasible to create a different instance of it each time the program runs.

I tried to use the undocumented "CollectGarbage" as other people had recommended but it still doesn't fix the problem.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kill the task in task manager using the same activex object. Try the below

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("taskkill /F /IM EXCEL.exe");
```

TASKKILL

End one or more processes (by process id or image name).

Syntax
      TASKKILL [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
         { [/FI filter] [/PID processid | /IM imagename] } [/F] [/T]

Options
    /S   system           The remote system to connect to.

```
/U   [domain\]user    The user context under which
                      the command should execute.

/P   [password]       The password. Prompts for input if omitted.

/F                    Forcefully terminate the process(es).

/FI  filter           Display a set of tasks that match a
                      given criteria specified by the filter.

/PID process id       The PID of the process to be terminated.

/IM  image name       The image name of the process to be terminated.
                      Wildcard '*' can be used to specify all image names.

/T                     Tree kill: terminates the specified process
                       and any child processes which were started by it.
```

Filters    Apply one of the Filters below:

```
         Imagename   eq, ne                  String
         PID         eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le  Positive integer.
         Session     eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le  Any valid session number.
         Status      eq, ne                  RUNNING | NOT RESPONDING
         CPUTime     eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le  Time hh:mm:ss
         MemUsage    eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le  Any valid integer.
         Username    eq, ne                  User name ([Domain\]User).
         Services    eq, ne                  String The service name
         Windowtitle eq, ne                  String
         Modules     eq, ne                  String The DLL name
```

Comment: This accomplishes the job, just a little too well. Could it be limited to the most recent instance? In other words a user may have another excel file loaded when the program runs, could a clause be added such that, "taskkill most recent Excel.exe". Also thank you very much for your help

Comment: Yes you can. Everytime when you open a excel process, save the process id and use the same to close it. I post some command below in answer. Build your own command as per your need.